# Find command always returns errorlevel as zero

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am trying get the status of a remote process using tasklist command using following code,

```
for /f "tokens=1-2 delims=," %%A in (TaskList.txt) do (
        SET ServerName=
        SET taskName=
        SET _ServerName=%%A
        SET _taskName=%%B

        echo !_ServerName!,!_taskName!

        tasklist.exe /s !_ServerName! /u nbccadmin /p Project@123 /FI " IMAGENAME eq !_taskName!" > Result.txt

        Find /i "PID" < Result.txt
        echo %ERRORLEVEL%
        IF %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 (
            echo !_ServerName!,!_taskName!,Running >> TaskStatus.csv
        )

        find /i "No tasks are running" < Result.txt
        echo %ERRORLEVEL%
        IF %ERRORLEVEL%==0 (
            echo !_ServerName!,!_taskName!,Not Running >> TaskStatus.csv
        )
    )
```

Issue I am facing is that when I use the FIND command to search the value "PID" or "No tasks are running", the ERRORLEVEL returned is always 0, even if the process is not running.

I didnt get why is it so.

Please help me with this issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Within a block statement `(a parenthesised series of statements)`, the **entire** block is parsed and **then** executed. Any `%var%` within the block will be replaced by that variable's value **at the time the block is parsed** - before the block is executed - the same thing applies to a `FOR ... DO (block)`.

Hence, `%errorlevel%` is replaced by the value of `errorlevel` at parse-time.

You can use `!errorlevel!` since you evidently have invoked `enabledelayedexpansion` (since you use `!var!` but haven't shown us the entire batch.)

Or you could use `errorlevel` in its original form,

```
if errorlevel n dosomething
```

which is true if `errorlevel` is `n` **or greater than** `n`. In this form, `errorlevel` is the **run-time** value of `errorlevel`.

And since you are interested in `errorlevel==0` then the common form is

```
if not errorlevel 1 (dothis) else (dothat)
```

(even if I abhor double-negatives.)